# Azure Logic App FTP Connector Issue: Invalid Connection

Tags: ftp, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to setup FTP trigger using FTP Connector in Azure logic Apps. However, I can't make it to work. I have even tried to connect to public test FTP server but it still shows invalid connection.
Shown below are the connection details for Public FTP. The exception I face is Invalid Connection on designer. The Exception Detail  is: Details: Ftp Password is empty or was not provided
[image: FTP Details]

I am not sure if I am missing anything. I have tried testing with other SFTP server on port 22 but in vain.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it FTP or SFTP? Or FTPS?
I see you're using port 22.

Did you try ticking `Enable SSL?` `Disable Certificate Validation?`

Did you try using `SFTP - SSH` connector?

Comment: Simple Conenction:
Error 502. An FTP protocol violation was detected. This could be caused by an implicit TLS/SSL configuration of the FTP server that is not supported. Please try explicit TLS/SSL

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried all option but in vain. However, it gave me idea to try SFTP-SSH option which worked.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the conenction again. I was provided an SFTP option, and that what I needed to use.
Changing from simple FTP to SFTP resolvd the issues.